# remove unsubscribed subscriptions

Tags: pusher, laravel-lighthouse

- Laravel6
- lighthouse-php5

I'm using lighthouse-php for GraphQL Subscription and I receive the message from pusher.

So I have the question of Subscription unsubscribe.

server side => pusher => front side

Documantation this part means just stop **pusher => front side**.
If I don't remove the redis, still server side working and push message to pusher, right?

```
  unsubscribeFromChannel(subscriptionChannel) {
    this.pusher.unsubscribe(subscriptionChannel);
  }
```

I want to stop **server side => pusher** too.
What options I have?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the Lighthouse documentation, a direct link here: https://lighthouse-php.com/5/subscriptions/getting-started.html#expiring-subscriptions.

But also some snippets here just in case it helps.

> Subscriptions do not expire by themselves. Unless you delete a subscription, it will continue to broadcast events after the client has disconnected.
>
> The easiest way to expire subscriptions automatically is to use the env LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE_TTL to set an expiration time in seconds (e.g. LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE_TTL=3600 to expire in one hour).

So setting this `.env` variable is a great way to expire subscriptions that are left behind automatically, do set this timeout large enough, if you have a lot of long running subscriptions an hour might not be enough.

But since you are using Pusher there is a faster way to cleanup the subscriptions:

> If you are using the Pusher driver, you can use a Presence webhook to mitigate this problem. When a Pusher channel is abandoned (ie. unsubscribed), it will trigger the webhook, which will instruct Lighthouse to delete the subscription.

This webhook (channel existence webhook as Pusher calls them) will remove subscriptions for channels that are vacated (no subscribers left) this will happen a few seconds after the user disconnects keeping the subscriptions in Redis up-to-date.

---

So long story short, setup a TTL for the subscriptions as a fallback and configure the Pusher webhook for your app. This will keep the subscriptions stored up-to-date and prevent unneeded work.

Comment: Thanks Alex!! I didn't read document this part. Thank you so much.
I try to set .env and check!!

Comment: No worries, hope it worked for you! Don't forget to update here so we know this was the solution (or not) for future readers.

Comment: I set the `xxx//graphql/subscriptions/webhook`  on pusher webhooks page. But pusher doesn't call the this url after unsubscribed and vacated.

[Pusher doc](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels/) wrote must be prefixed with presence- ....

So subscription return the channel name like private-lighthouse-xxxx. I try to prefixed presence- like presence-private-lighthouse-xxxx on frontend and call pusher.subscribe(this channel name). But it doesn't work.

I want to know where presence channel create. Pusher setting? Or some setting on lighthouse?

Comment: One more question. You mean LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_TTL setting call delete ghost redis, right? I set this but any redis are not deleted. My front end call only pusher.unsubscribe. And wait minutes I set LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_TTL. So I want to know how to test this?

Comment: You need to create a ["channel existence"](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks/#channel-existence-events) webhook. Not a presence webhook.

Comment: Setting LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_TTL is incorrect, it seems like the docs mention the wrong key too unfortunately and I've just copied and pasted that, it needs to be LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE_TTL, sorry for the confusion. I've updated the answer and will create a PR to change the docs too!

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I change this and test both.
Setting LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE_TTL delete redis after that setting minutes.
And  webhook delete redis after unsubscribe soon.

Comment: Perfect, glad it worked, I've also updated the answer, so don't forget to mark it as so if it solved your question :)